# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'filename' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\dir.php on line 9

Tags: php, active-directory

```
**php program for reading filenames and filetypes from a dir.**
```

it shows the syntax error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'filename' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\dir.php on line 9

```
<?php
$dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\php\"; 
if(is_dir($dir)) 
 {
 if($dirref=opendir($dir))
   {
     while(($file=readdir($dirref))!==false)
      {
      echo "filename : $file : filetype: ".filetype($dir.$file)."\n";
      }
   closedir($dirref);
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Look at the highlighting done on your post, that should show you your problem

Comment: Don't use ``\`` in file paths in windows-based PHP code. Use `/`, PHP will auto-translate to the proper directory separators for you. This will eliminate problems like the one you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you've escaped the closing quotes on your `$dir=` statement.  I don't use php in a Windows environment, so I don't know if you can convert all your `\` to `/`, but if not, you'll want to escape all the `\`:

```
$dir="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\";
```

Or use single quotes, which disables escape sequences:

```
$dir='C:\xampp\htdocs\php\';
```

Parse errors often indicate that there is a syntax (or string in this case) error in your code, BEFORE the error actually reported by the parser.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on your first line: $dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\php\";

The backslash escapes the quotes.

Escape the backslashes in your code to make it work, like so:

```
$dir="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\";
```

Comment: yup!!!solved.....thanks a ton....but filetype it is showing as file /dir not php or html file which i ws xpecting

Answer (score 0):

`$dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\php\";`

Just remove the last **'\'** and make it

```
$dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\php";
```

It will Work..!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\php\";
```

to

```
$dir="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\";
```

Comment: I believe the `if($dirref=opendir($dir))` is intentional.  Check for `true` and assign.

Comment: Yes... you are right... @SuperJer